# TSQL How to select SQL records with following where condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table Test with records

```
ID             Date    
1            12/08/2017
1            11/10/2016
1            06/09/2010
1            06/29/2009
2            05/29/2009
2            03/29/2009
2            02/29/2009
```

I want to select id's where Date >2010 but I want to include all record dates 
I tried this

```
select * from Test
where Date >='01/01/2010'
```

but this return only 3 records of id 1. If only all dates of id are less than 2010 then my select query should not select that ID. if the id has one or more dates >2010 then include in select. Do I need to put in a sub query?

Comment: Your query gives you the correct result.  There is at least a record > 2009.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM Test t
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
               FROM Test
               WHERE ID = t.ID 
               AND Date >= '01/01/2010'
             )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the query below.  You have to exclude any IDs that have record before '01/01/2010'

```
SELECT *
FROM Test t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Test
    WHERE ID = t.ID AND Date < '01/01/2010'
)
```

Comment: Yes because I thought you only want records that have no entry before '01/01/2010'